# Should we merge Google Hangouts tags with Google Chat?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Recently, I had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75478309/what-is-the-limit-of-google-chat-message-card-via-chatbot) related to Google Chat API. When I created that question I chose [google-chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chat) and [google-chat-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chat-api) for the tag.

After that, someone commented on my question, and he advice me to ask a Google Chat support expert. So I visited that link, but unfortunately no support information for the google chat. They are only for other services if using the link that was given by the commentator. But I searched online and found
https://developers.google.com/chat/support .

In that link, Google itself recommend us to ask on Stack Overflow using [hangouts-chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangouts-chat) tag. That makes me confused. Google Hangouts was renamed to Google Chat, right? Why still use the "hangouts-chat" term?

There are also other similar tags, [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts), [hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangouts), and [hangouts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangouts-api)

Should we merge all of these tags?

Since Google Hangouts is upgraded to Google Chat, I think we should move all Google Hangouts tags to the Google Chat tag. And also maybe ask Google itself to change the tag on the chat support page?

Comment: "Google Hangouts was renamed to Google Chat, right" - Not exactly. There was the old chat functionality that existed inside the old Google Hangouts, and now there is Google Chat. The old platform appears to have breathed it's last on January 1, 2023. They co-existed for a while though.

Comment: We should just have one tag for google-owned chat products, and synonymize any new ones to it as they are created, because that's how Google treats its actual chat products.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is in progress. I still need some feedback before proceeding any further.

What I have done so far:

1. I've merged [hangouts-chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangouts-chat) and [hangout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangout) into [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) after confirming that they did indeed refer to the same thing. (This cannot be undone)
2. I've created a synonym from [hangouts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangouts-api) to [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts). I have not merged these tags; I do not know if there is some meaningful difference between the API for hangouts and the hangouts product itself. I would assume the answer is "no," but I wanted to give some more time for someone to raise an objection.
3. I've created a synonym from [google-chat-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chat-api) to [google-chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chat), but have not merged for the same reasons as [hangouts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangouts-api) and [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts).

<sub>(The synonyms can be undone if needed)</sub>

---

I have **not** merged or synonymised [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) and [google-chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chat) tags. Since a merge is something that cannot be undone, I want to give some more time for input either in favour of merging or arguments against it.

I can certainly see a valid argument that keeping the historical/deprecated Hangouts tags separate from the modern Google Chat API tags makes it easier for researchers to discover the modern solutions and exclude those that are deprecated. As an example, searches like [[google-chat] -[google-hangouts]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chat+-google-hangouts) are possible as long as the tags remain separate, but would become impossible if the tags were synonymised/merged.

Having said that, I have almost no knowledge of the topic and do not know anything about how much overlap there is between the technologies to determine if the distinction is helpful or not in practice. Considering how frequently *all* of these tags appeared on the same questions [[google-hangouts] [google-chat]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts+google-chat), I'm not sure how useful the distinction is currently but, if needed and with some disambiguation, we could probably get to a reasonable state.

Comment: *"As a note, I cannot create a synonym..."* Sure you can. Create the synonym in the direction that the system forces you to create it, based on the number of questions, and then "swap" it on the Tag Synonyms page.

Comment: @CodyGray I've had trouble with that myself. Swapping works, but it's like the system doesn't respect it. Tried waiting out the caches, but didn't work

Comment: Are you sure they're synonymous? Hangouts used to include video right? But then that got moved to the Meet branding. So, there might be older `google-hangouts` questions about video that shouldn't be merged.

Comment: @SteveBennett are you suggesting having a separate [tag:google-hangouts-video] and [tag:google-hangouts-chat] tags? That distinction did not exist in the previously existing tags. The previous tags [tag:google-hangouts] and [tag:hangout] did refer to all of chat, video, and API in actual use.

Comment: Though I would agree that [tag:hangouts-chat] is perhaps an overly specific name and that [tag:google-hangouts] would probably be a better for the entire group of tags as it refers more to the product than the feature. That'd be an easy change to make if that's a better name.

Comment: Shouldn't we opt for [tag:google-chat] to instead synonymize to [tag:google-chat-api]? Presumably the latter is the only on-topic aspect of google chat here on SO...

Answer (score 2):

Google Hangouts and Google Chat are the names of two different products. For a time, both products were run in parallel, each of them having their URL https://hangouts.google.com and https://chat.google.com, respectively, their mobile apps and Gmail users had the option to use one or another platform for as the embedded chat service. I'm not sure about the APIs.

Google Hangouts is no longer available. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Hangouts

> On June 27, 2022, Google officially announced they would be shutting down Google Hangouts in November 1, 2022 and migrating all users to Google Chat.[33]

Regarding the tags in Stack Overflow, I think that [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) should be kept for questions about the product that used to have a URL https://hangouts.google.com even the users were migrated to Google Chat, and the old Hangouts URL nowadays redirects to https://chat.google.com.

Most questions created after November 1, 2022 with the tag [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) should be reviewed to evaluate if they are really about Google Hangouts or using it as a common name, like using "excel" instead of spreadsheet.

---

I have forgotten to mention in the above section that **Google Meet** now serves some of the video call conference features of Google Hangouts.

The Event resource of the **Google Calendar API** still uses "Hangout". In some sections, the documentation mentions that it's deprecated, but others explain that it's currently referring to Google Meet.

I don't think that questions created after November 1, 2022, about the Google Calendar API that uses one of the properties using "hangouts" as part of the property should use the tag [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts). [google-calendar-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api) and a tag corresponding to the programming language should be used instead.

---

More findings: Several questions have [google-meet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-meet), but there isn't an API for Google Meet. So far, I found that most questions using this tag mention problems when creating a Google Calendar event. Not all these questions have [google-calendar-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api).

A future tag clean-up project, if it doesn't already exist, might be to remove [google-meet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-meet)  and add [google-calendar-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api) if the question tries to create a Google Calendar event with a link to a Google Meet meeting, new or one already existing.

Comment: Also, those using the tag [tag:google-hangouts] to create a new question in SO nowadays will likely have no idea of programming. Probably, they are asking a question that is not about programming.

Comment: I've reviewed all six questions posted after that date, and apart from one [overly broad/unclear one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74696019) (which I have closed), they all appear to be about programming.  They all (with some exceptions where I can't tell if it's actually related to either product, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75067650)) appear to be about Google Chat rather than Google Hangouts.  Many of the questions before that date _also_ appear to be about Google Chat.