# What to do with the [google-meet] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

This is in some way related to [Should we merge Google Hangouts tags with Google Chat?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423317/1595451)

Google Meet is an online conference platform from Google. It substitutes the service provided by Google+ Hangouts / Google Hangouts, but not 100%. There is no API, but there is an SDK developer preview. For details, see https://developers.google.com/meet.

Here we have [google-meet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-meet). It has no tag wiki and has 103 questions.

It is related to [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) but more importantly to [google-calendar-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api).

The relation with [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) is historic in the minds of many computer users. Several questions using [google-meet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-meet) are not about programming or are using it because they are about trying to do some automation, i.e., creating a web browser extension, injecting client-side code, or are questions about creating or adding a Google Meet conference link to a Google Calendar event.

Should we add a tag wiki? If so, what the tag wiki should say in this case?

Comment: "Several questions using google-meet are not about programming" did you mean "are about programming"? If they are not about programming then they should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @MT0 I mean exactly that, several questions tagged [tag:google-meet] are not about programming. I have already voted to close as not about programming all that I found that correspond to this case.

Comment: If there is a SDK for it then the tag itself is justified. As for non-programming questions - they pop up below many tags, just close them when you spot them. In case of low traffic tags, consider also posting a close-vote request in the [SO close vote review chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to ensure that it will get closed.

Comment: @Lundin I have forgotten about that chatroom, my bad. Thanks. I just reported the first. I will be reporting more later.

Comment: @Rubén: You are one of the few users actively engaging in curation, your efforts are worthy of celebration, you forgetting the close vote chatroom is nothing to feel bad about, really!

Comment: Thanks @MatthieuM. I can't avoid feeling sorry for failing at things I learned some time ago... I'm working on that. By the way, I also have forgotten that the close vote review chatroom has some rules. The basic Internet etiquette to remember each "forum" (site / community / chatroom) might have its rules: look if the place has a description / welcome message, no description, follow common sense, if it have a description, **READ IT**, specially if you have memory problems like me :P

Comment: @Rubén: Honestly, I remember the room exists, but never uses it. I nigh only peruse the rust tag, and there's a Rust chatroom that is used among ourselves to ask for close-votes :)

Answer (score 1):

I have "unilateraly" decided that the first version of the [google-meet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-meet) tag wiki should point people to this question.

It's not worth investing too much effort yet on the tag wiki because most users likely to use this tag will not read the tag excerpt and body. A few people might read it, probably a few who found questions with this tag on the review queues or those interested in helping with curation.

I don't think that without further discussion, the tag usage guidelines should limit the use of this tag to questions about using the Google Meet Live SDK as there are some questions in some way related to Google Meet about

1. Creating browser extensions to extend or extract data from Google Meet.
2. Using web browser developer tools to extend or extract data from Google Meet.
3. Automate Google Meet using Puppeteer or similar tools.
4. Creating Google Calendar events with a link to a Google Meet conference.

On the other hand, questions asking about web browser settings and Google Meet settings, among other usage stuff, should be closed as not about programming.

---

**SO Close Vote Reviewers chatroom**

Remember that this chatroom has rules about the questions that can be reported. The details are in the chatroom description.